# Check if a string is a correct linear function - java

Tags: java, function, math, jfreechart

how can I check if a string is a correct linear function (mathematical)?

I use Jfreechart  library, in which needed a linear function to draw the graph.
Jfree library has a Function2D class for that and I use it like that:

```
package NALIG;

import org.jfree.data.function.Function2D;

import expr.Expr;
import expr.Parser;
import expr.SyntaxException;
import expr.Variable;

/**
 * The function.
*/
public class Fx implements Function2D {

private String formula;

public Fx(String f){
    formula = f;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.jfree.data.function.Function2D#getValue(double)
 */
public double getValue(double x) {

    Expr expr = null;

    try {
        expr = Parser.parse(formula);
    } catch (SyntaxException e) {
        System.err.println("formula error syntaxExeption");
        System.err.println(e.explain());
    }
    Variable vx = Variable.make("x");
    vx.setValue(x);



    return expr.value();
}
}
```

but the thing is that the syntaxExeption is not working very correctly(mathematically).
No syntaxExeption throwed in follow examples (which mathematically is incorrect):

```
f(x)=xd   not throw error
f(x)=1+xd not throw error
```

work properly for the follow:

```
f(x)=;  (or starting with any other symbol or alone symbol: !@#$%^&*()_+;'[]{}|\")  throw syntaxExeption
f(x)=x+ (or any other symbol in position of "+" like !@#$%^&*()_+;'[]{}|\")  throw syntaxExeption
```

***THE INPUT String FOR CHECKING IS AFTER =

***The source code of SyntaxExeption is [here](https://github.com/darius/expr/blob/master/expr/SyntaxException.java)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The syntex is not clearly defined. Probably what you need is javacc which allows you to define your own grammar.

Comment: @KelvinNg you not helping me sorry...

Answer (score 0):

You do this the same way you confirm that any other input is well-formed: by trying to parse it.

Look up the formal grammar of the language you're using to express the functions. Implement a parser for that language -- either by recursive descent or by using one of the "compiler compiler" toolkits like javacc or the older lex/yacc pair. If the parser discovers that the input diverges from the acceptable formal grammar, report the error. Depending on the language, you may need to deal with building a symbol table and tracking subexpression types and doing other kinds of cross-checking; those operations can often be driven by the parser, or at least the data gathering can be driven by the parser with a post-parsing pass to analyze that data.

Depending on the structure of the language and how hard you're willing to work, you may or may not be able to report more than one error per attempt. But simple yes/no well-formedness checking is usually straightforward.

Details, I'm afraid, would go beyond the reasonable scope of a Stack Overflow answer.